# Counting number of working days and weekends using PHP/ MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to calculate the number of weekdays worked and the number of weekend days worked from data i retrieve out of a MySQL database.

The time from the DB is formatted like this : 2013-07-01 07:00

This is what I have so far:

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    $check = date("w", strtotime($date));
        if ($check == 6 || $check == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
}

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT date from jobcards");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $date = $row['date'];
  $date_check= isWeekend($date);

  if ($date_check == 1) {
  ++$weekend;
  }
  else {
  ++$workday;
  }

}
```

I need to find a way to count the days using mysql instead, is there such a way or a more elegant way to improve the PHP code ?

Also if I have multiple records in the database with the same date range but a different time example: 2013-07-01 07:00 and 2013-07-01 07:30 it will be counted as two workdays, how would i prevent that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the **WEEKDAY** function, and compare it to 6/5 for Sunday/Saturday (respectively)

Your SQL will look something like:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(WEEKDAY(date) >= 5, 1, 0) AS WeekendCount,
       SUM(IF(WEEKDAY(date) < 5, 1, 0) AS WeekdayCount
FROM jobcards
```

There is a similar answer here: [MySQL Weekday/Weekend count - Part II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191462/mysql-weekday-weekend-count-part-ii)

*Fixed the ) of the IF being placed in the wrong place*

Comment: That solved it thanks so much, I had to change the query a little bit though, your parentheses was in the wrong place :)

Comment: Speaking of how would i select 1 record per day ? if there are multiple records for the one day

Comment: Please provide table structure if you want us to give you an answer for "multiple records per day" part of your question.

Comment: For example: columns: id,name,date,call Record 1 values: 1,Matt,2013-07-01 17:00, 12345.   Record 2: 2,Matt,2013,07-01 18:00

Comment: So add after **FROM jobcards**, **GROUP BY call, date**. I think this is what you are looking for, if not give the original question more details of desired output and sample data.

Comment: group by date will not group as record1 -  2013-07-01 17:00 and record2 - 2013-07-01 18:00 has different values

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake, **GROUP BY call, name**, anyway, I suggest you open another question and give an example of your, data, structure of table, and current output, and then ask how to achieve desired output - a lot easier than continuing with this thread

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(date) BETWEEN 2 AND 6,1,0) AS weekdays,
SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(date) NOT BETWEEN 2 AND 6,1,0) AS weekends,
FROM jobcards
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, 
sum(date) total, 
sum(if(date_format(date,'%w') between 1 and 5),1,0) weekday,
sum(date) - sum(if(date_format(date,'%w') between 1 and 5),1,0) weekend
from jobcards
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in SQL, you can solve the timestamp problem using the MySQL [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function, and the [DAYOFWEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function to count your weekdays/weekends (Note that the day numbers for Sat/Sun are 7/1 in MySQL and not 6/0 as in PHP).  So to count the distinct weekday entries it would look something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobcards WHERE DAYOFWEEK(DATE(jobcards.date)) BETWEEN 2 AND 6;
```